# Local time zones with headless chrome in a lambda layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-chrome-headless

I'm running headless chrome in a lambda layer (https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda).

Issue is, I am trying to call .toLocaleString("en-AU"), but everything comes out as UTC/GMT regardless. I have read that node didn't always ship with internationalization options. I'm assuming something along those lines is what is going on here.

Any suggestions for how to work around this?

Comment: I think the best bet is to use moment.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `moment.js` for better control over time and time formats in NodeJS Lambda

https://momentjs.com/timezone/

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

newYork.format();    // 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
losAngeles.format(); // 2014-06-01T09:00:00-07:00
london.format();     // 2014-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```

Check their announcement about it's future and complications, including internationalization
https://momentjs.com/docs/